# load image url into editText

Tags: android, mysql

I need to insert a URL Image into EditText and able to save it to my **Mysql**.

- I need to broswe all the images from my local server (**SOLVED**).
- Then I want to select one image and display the selected url image into  a EditText(**Problem**).
- So that I will save the selected url image into mysql database (**No Problem with that**)
- Pluz how to return to my form after i selected the image (**Problem**)

Here my code for browsing the list of images into my local server :

```
checkButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.browser);

        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/images/";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }

        });
```

Comment: ??what you want to show on edittext, wheather url or image itself, if image, then use drwable to set imageDrawable in background for edittext.

Comment: I need to show selected url image

Comment: tell me that you want to want to show image as small part(inside editext) of your edittext or display that image completely in place of edittext

Comment: I need to show selected url image

Comment: please confirm me, once you click on button, android will open a web browser, and you are browsing images in a web page right?

Comment: then this should be donein JavaScript, of that html page.

Answer (score 0):

if you have URL for image, then you can retrieve Bitmap for image from server.
then you can build a Drwable from Bitmap-

```
    Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

And then for setting background in EditText

```
 editText.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: this code it giving me an error  editText.setImageDrwable(d); so how can i go back to my form ?

Comment: my mistake, its setBackgroundDrawable()

Comment: Eish! I can get you, but the problem now when i select that image , i need to go back to my form but i cant

Comment: for that you have to edit your question and provide complete explanation of your problem, what exactly you want and what you doing and getting. We can provide you solution only if we understand your problem...